# Is reinforcement learning a subset of unsupervised learning?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

According to [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210115215040/https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/introduction-reinforcement-learning):

> Reinforcement learning on the other hand, **which is a subset of Unsupervised learning** ...

How true is this statement? Is there any scholarly discussion/writing on the classifications of Reinforcement learning?

Comment: The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning) article clearly mentions *Reinforcement learning is one of three basic machine learning paradigms, alongside supervised learning and unsupervised learning.*

Answer (score 5):

*Reinforcement* learning differs from ***Unsupervised*** learning as it uses additional information regarding the expected behavior of the agent in the form of a reward function. However, it also differs from ***Supervised*** learning as it does not require any labelled data for training or testing.

So, it is neither of them. You may also refer to the wiki page of *Reinforcement* learning for further related details.

Answer (score 1):

No, Reinforcement Learning and Unsupervised Learning are considered two different paradigms.

We can refer to the seminal book [*Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning*](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387310732) by Christopher Bishop for their respective definitions:

- Unsupervised learning:

  > In other pattern recognition problems, the training data consists of a set of input vectors x without any corresponding target values. The goal in such unsupervised learning problems may be to discover groups of similar examples within the data, where it is called clustering, or to determine the distribution of data within the input space, known as density estimation, or to project the data from a high-dimensional space down to two or three dimensions for the purpose of visualization
- Reinforcement learning:

  > Finally, the technique of reinforcement learning [...] is concerned with the problem of finding suitable actions to take in a given situation in order to maximize a reward.

As you can see, their goals are completely different: while in unsupervised learning we don't have labels and we are aiming at discovering the *structure* of the data, in reinforcement learning we want to learn a strategy to maximize the obtained rewards according to a reward signal.

Answer (score 0):

### The three different learning paradigms

The Neural Networks: A Comprehensive Foundation (Simon Haykin) divides learning methods in these categories:

- Learning with a teacher: Supervised learning
- Learning without a teacher:

  - Reinforcement learning / Neurodynamic programming
  - Unsupervised learning

So essentially, there are three different learning paradigms: **Supervised learning**, **Reinforcement learning** and **Unsupervised Learning**.

### Similarities and differences

**Reinforcement learning** and **unsupervised learning** have the *similarity* that you will not need training data to begin with (no target y-values, so no "teacher" to provide the desired response).

But **reinforcement learning** is not unsupervised, as it needs "continued interaction with the environment in order to minimize a scalar index of performance" [Haykin]. In **unsupervised learning** the network "develops the ability to form internal representations for encoding features of the input and thereby to create new classes automatically" [Haykin]. It has no feedback loop with the environment as reinforcement learning has; It has *just* the input dataset.

### Takeaway

Reinforcement learning *is not* a subset of Unsupervised learning; the statement in the article is false. But they both are learning *without a teacher*.